# jQuery .mouseout() and .click() issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm currently doing some jQuery on the side and have come across a frustrating problem. I have a `div#img1` that is set to `0.5 opacity` by default. Currently it fades to `opacity: 1;` when the mouse hovers over the `div#img1` , and fades back to `opacity: 0.5;` when the mouse leaves the `div#img1` . However when I click on `#img1` I want the div to be set at an opacity of `opacity: 1;` for good.

For some reason, it seems to still respond to the mouseleave (causing the opacity to go back to 0.5 after the click)

```
var fade = function(object,delay,fadeTime,Opacity){
    $(object).delay(delay).fadeTo(fadeTime,Opacity);
};

var moveX = function(object,delay,position,moveTime){
    $(object).delay(delay).animate({left:position},moveTime);
};

var moveY = function(object,delay,position,moveTime){
    $(object).delay(delay).animate({top:position},moveTime);
};

$(".image").mouseenter(function(){
    fade(this,0,0,1);
    $("p",this).fadeTo(0,1);
});

$(".image").mouseleave(function(){
    fade(this,0,0,0.5);
    $("p",this).fadeTo(0,0);
});

$("#img1").click(function(){
    moveY('#project',0,'-65%',1000);
    moveY('#img2',0,'-34%',1000);
    moveY('#img1',0,'25%',1000);
    moveX('#img1',0,'10%',1000);
    $('#img1').css("opacity","1");
    $('#img1 p').fadeTo(0,1);
    moveX('#imgHelper1',1000,'50%',1000);
});
```

Is there any easy fix I can make so that the mouseleave command dosn't trigger once I click the div?

Comment: Can you add a js bin or js fiddle to see the code in action?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to set a variable to true once you click the div and just execute the code in the mouseleave-function if this variable is not true.

```
var clicked = false;
$(".image").mouseleave(function(){
  if(!clicked){
    fade(this,0,0,0.5);
    $("p",this).fadeTo(0,0);
  }
});

$("#img1").click(function(){
  clicked=true;
  moveY('#project',0,'-65%',1000);
  moveY('#img2',0,'-34%',1000);
  moveY('#img1',0,'25%',1000);
  moveX('#img1',0,'10%',1000);
  $('#img1').css("opacity","1");
  $('#img1 p').fadeTo(0,1);
  moveX('#imgHelper1',1000,'50%',1000);
});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks!

I was originally thinking of using an if statement using the position of the #img1 div (since it moves once clicked) but this solution is so much better and simpler!

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/
Store arbitrary data associated with the specified element and/or return the value that was set.

```
$(".image").mouseleave(function(){
  if(!$(this).data('clicked')) {
    fade(this,0,0,0.5);
    $("p",this).fadeTo(0,0);
  }
});

$("#img1").click(function(){
  $(this).data('clicked', true);
  // More code ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would a little bit of css work for you ??

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/deDVY/1/)**

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/people" id="lol"/>
```

---

```
$('#lol').on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('fullVisible');
});
```

---

```
#lol{
    opacity:0.5;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#lol:hover{
    opacity:1;
}

img.fullVisible{
    opacity:1 !Important;
}
```